# Caching Issue around Multiple Eclipse Instances

Tags: python, java, eclipse, caching, eclipse-plugin

I was running a single eclipse instance (Windows) for some time for Java, Python development. I decided this week to replace that single instance with two additional instances of eclipse - one for Java dev and one for Py dev. The idea here was to have two separate eclipse workspaces for each instance (each instance having difference plugins).

I deleted the old eclipse folder that held all the eclipse exe and deleted the old workspace. But I think I am missing some steps. My Py dev instance seems to be linked to my deleted eclipse instance somehow (I know this because the color theme is the same as last time). And I am also have some issues with downloading plugins on both instances - signature errors on install. Any ideas on how I can clean this up?

Comment: It's hard to guess without more details about what exactly you're experiencing. I can offer some facts that might help: 1) I've done this many times (had multiple installations of Eclipse at the same time). 2) Eclipse installations are, mostly, encapsulated - there is no shared data between them like registry or shared libs, etc. 3) Eclipse workspaces are not to be shared between different installations.

Comment: I will try my best to provide the correct details, but I am also new to Eclipse IDE. Originally, I installed eclipse version X at my ~/Users/<me>/, which is also where my workspace was contained.

I then installed two additional instances (version X, and version Y) of eclipse at ~/Users/<me>/Tools/Folder1 and ~/Users/<me>/Tools/Folder2. The additional workspaces are within ~/Users/<me> directory. 

I then deleted my original eclipse instance but when I open my new version X of eclipse, I still see the same theme that I used previously. Which seems odd to me bc this should be a net new.